# Vue js : filter data from API

Tags: javascript, vue.js

in my project below, i have an API that contains 36 buildings, in each building 22 levels and in each floor there are 6 flats ... i wanted to view all these data in table for each building and till now floors are good but i'm stuck to show 6 flats in each level .. in my below code it gives me the flats for all the building id clicked. However, in my post method i specified each of this detail so API is good but i don't have an idea on how to  implement flats in each floor.

```js
<template>
    <b-card no-body class="bg-default shadow">
  
 <b-table-simple responsive>
  <b-thead>
    <b-tr >
      <b-th sticky-column>Sticky Column Header  </b-th>
      <b-th >
      
      </b-th>
   
    </b-tr>
  </b-thead>
  <b-tbody >
    <b-tr  v-for="(floor, floor_index) in Building.floors"
              :key="index">
      <b-th sticky-column>{{floor_index}}</b-th>
      <b-td>Cell</b-td>
 
    </b-tr>
  </b-tbody>
 </b-table-simple>

 <div v-for="(floor, floor_index) in Building.floors" :key="floor_index"> //this code gives me number 6 22 times
  <pre  style="color:white;"> {{floor.flats.length}} </pre>
  
</div>
    </b-card>
    
</template>
<script>
  import projects from './../projects'
  import { Table, TableColumn} from 'element-ui'
  import BuildingsService from "@/services/ApiService"
  export default {
    name: 'light-table',
    components: {

    },
    data() {
      return {
          Flats:[],
          index:0,
          Floors:[],
          Building:[],
        projects,
        currentPage: 1
      };
    },

mounted: function(){
 
      
      BuildingsService.getOneBuilding(`${this.$route.params.id}`).then((response) => {
      this.Building = response.data.response;
 this.NoOfFloors = this.Building.floors;

console.log(this.Building.floors,"single");
   

    });

        BuildingsService.getFlats().then((response) => {
      this.Flats = response.data.response;
 
// console.log(response.data.response,"singfle");

    });


    }
  }
</script>
```

```html
{"response":[{"floors":[{"flats":[{"status":"Available","price":"Not set","currency":"USD","_id":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c3a0","flat_number":0,"description":"This is a newly created flat.","city":"Istanbul","payment_type":null,"floor":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c39f","building":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c39e","createdAt":"2021-12-18T15:31:14.383Z","updatedAt":"2021-12-18T15:31:14.383Z","__v":0},{"status":"Available","price":"Not set","currency":"USD","_id":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c3a1","flat_number":1,"description":"This is a newly created flat.","city":"Istanbul","payment_type":null,"floor":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c39f","building":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c39e","createdAt":"2021-12-18T15:31:14.384Z","updatedAt":"2021-12-18T15:31:14.384Z","__v":0},{"status":"Available","price":"Not set","currency":"USD","_id":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c3a2","flat_number":2,"description":"This is a newly created flat.","city":"Istanbul","payment_type":null,"floor":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c39f","building":"61bdfebd1d7df1a88b70c39e",
```

update: i want to get the indexes of this array
[image]

Comment: Can you share an example of the data returned by the API, with the structure showing Buildings, Floors and Flats?

Comment: @match question edited

Comment: I guess the best thing if you want to keep using one table for each building is to add one row for each flat and add a `level` col. You would have then `level` and `flat` col for each row

Comment: I would try to restructure the data. Each flat has a `building`, `floor` and `flat` id - buidl new data structures based on these and then iterate over them.

Comment: @match please take a look at my updated question

Comment: @RenaudC5  please take a look at my updated question

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to nest `flats` inside `floors`, and then filter the `flats` based on the current `floor`. It looks like each `flat` has a `floor` property which presumably matches an property in `floor`. Assuming this is `floor.id`, you can do something like:

```
<div v-for="(floor, floor_index) in Building.floors" :key="floor_index">
  <pre>Floor: {{ floor }}</pre>
  <div v-for="(flat, flat_index) in Building.flats" :key="flat_index">
    <pre v=if="flat.floor === floor.id">Flat: {{ flat }}</pre>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: this didn't work :/  i wanted to show the flats (which are 6 flats ) in each floor that i showed from this function       `<b-tr  v-for="(building, index) in Building.floors"
              :key="index">
      <b-th sticky-column>{{index}}</b-th>`

Comment: Can you update your code to better show the data structure and exactly how you want it filtered? e.g. in the above code what does `building` look like, and how do you 'know' how to filter `flats` - i.e what property do they share etc?

Comment: the `building` same as floor, my problem is i can't show the 6 flats in each floor, i updated my code above please check it, it gives me the length 6 22 times while i want flats to be numbered from 0 to 6 only